# Did anyone know about update in Bastille for unix/linux?

Tags: linux, security, unix, hardening

I'm just wonder that bastille project is still active or not? which alternative tools are proper for both unix and linux?

Thanky you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very much still active, infact it was last updated only 9 days ago. Have a look at SF project page http://sourceforge.net/projects/bastille-linux/

Comment: Yeah. That's the reason I ask you here because after I click to this link http://sourceforge.net/projects/bastille-linux/files/bastille-linux/ the file is still 2008!!!

Comment: Well that was the last official release, there have still been tonnes of work done. See http://sourceforge.net/projects/bastille-linux/develop  for example, you can see lots of stuff is happening. I am guessing he had other stuff to do for a while hence no recent release. On the other hand, sometimes things reach 1.0 and there really isn't much more to *do* until someone suggests etc.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. Actually people will be happier if it's official release.

Comment: Please feel free to upvote me, I just did to you ;) Also, yea people would but he might not have done much since last release. It also requires a lot of testing.

Comment: i didn't have much rep. TwT